# python module for libnet in Opensuse

Tags: python, libnet

I have tried to run an `Python` program in my **Opensuse OS** this Program used `libnet` and pcap.

```
import queue
import sys
import socket
import libnet
from libnet.constants import *
import pcap
```

I have installed libnet-devel but when i run the program i recieve the folowing message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 9, in <module>
    import libnet
ImportError: No module named libnet
```

I have tried with different Python version, How can i solve this Problem?

Answer (score 1):

using the system python (the one in /usr/bin/python):

- make sure that python-pip is installed via yast
- download pylibnet from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pylibnet/
- install pylibnet with the command

  `sudo pip install ./pylibnet-3.0-beta-rc1.tar.gz`

there does not seem to be a version of pylibnet packaged and available through yast, which is why you need to install one using pip (which is a program for installing python packages).

libnet-devel only installs the c library - the above installs the python library.

[edit: forgot the "install" in the pip command; added download instructions]

Comment: i have tried to install with pip install pylibnet but `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pylibnet
No distributions at all found for pylibnet` what can i do

Comment: oh, ok.  looks like you need to download it yourself - see update above.